# FCM service worker setBackgroundMessageHandler

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to use FCM ([Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)) for Web Push Notification.
I successfully received a message when the web app tab was on focus.

But when I closed the tab, it was supposed to call the service worker ( which is `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in FCM sample ). But it didn't call the `setBackgroundMessageHandler` at all.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: 'firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: Did you set the `messagingSenderId`? Because aside from that your code looks the same as what I have - and that works. :-/

Comment: did u close the tab? i think it works when tab is not closed and not active

Answer (score 0):

Include following in your `manifest.json` file: 
`{"gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"}`
this `gcm_sender_id` is unique for all fcm users, its not specific to your project.

In your Service worker code add your project specific sender id. 
Working example of service worker code is [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js#L15-L29).

It should display background notification when your website tab is not in focus/ closed and browser is open.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem and I found a solution in this link: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71

Basically, the problem is the payload that you send. You need to use "data" object to setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload) function be called.

Example:

```
{
   "to": "cyn88sDUyZs:APA91bE...",
    "notification": 
    {
       "title": "Title",
       "body": "Body",
       "icon": "https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/2b50.png",
       "click_action": "https://www.test.com/"
    }
}
```

This will not call setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload) function because it does not use "data" object, so the notification object will take on and its properties will be on push message. But, if you use "data" object setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload) function will be called:

```
{
   "to": "cyn88sDUyZs:APA91bE...",
   "data":
   {
      "notification": 
      {
         "title": "Title",
         "body": "Body",
         "icon": "https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/2b50.png",
         "click_action": "https://www.test.com/"
      }
   }
}
```

So, in this case, Service Worker will execute what is inside the function. This function receive payload as parameter, then you can set payload properties as push message, set another message or call an API to do something, for example.